# Can't change material color of imported mesh by code

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have recently imported both .blend and .fbx files into my game, and I would like to change their color in-game. To color them, I am using diffuse shaders, and have tried this command:

```js
gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.red;
```

as well as this command:

```js
gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
```

For some reason, both of these work perfectly on pre-generated Unity cubes, but not on my models, even though they have the mesh renderer component. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that the meshes are on the object and not a child of that object? Also, are the base materials white by default?

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of the properties on the mesh you're trying to manipulate? (Specifically, expand all parts of the renderer component.) I think that'd help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons why your code doesn't work.
I would recommend changing the color of your object in the Editor, if it works - your objects are fine.

- _Color is just a label, that usually marks the Main Color. Open your shader and check if the label _Color exists or not. Please check this from unity documentation http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html
- maybe you are changing the _Color of the parent object, but the material you are looking at belongs to the child object.